# Rspec: expect to receive with block shortcut

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to write specs for code like `collection.map(&:something)`.

I know the easies way is to test the outcome of the block call, but in my case it calls 3rd party APIs and I just wanted to make sure it sends appropriate message to the collection.

Already tried a pretty straightforward `expect`:
`expect(collection).to receive(:map).with(&:something)`
It fails with `ArgumentError: 'with' must have at least one argument`.

What is the correct approach?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `something`, in this case, would be a message sent to the _elements_, not the collection. So something like this should work `expect(collection.first).to receive(:something)`. But I'm sensing that you actually don't have any elements or collection. The simplification of your actual code for the question may have gone too far.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev that makes sense. I solved it with `expect(collection).to all(receive(:something))`. Thank you!